# Uncaught (in Promise) Error When Using Polyfill for Porting Firefox Extensions to Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions, polyfills

I wrote a web extension for Firefox Quantum. The extension has a popup, which when clicked provides a 3 button menu. When one of the buttons is clicked, the extension will inject a DIV containing an iFrame into the user's current page.

Firefox extensions use the `promise` API and use the `browser` namespace instead of "callbacks" and the `chrome` namespace. As such, Mozilla provides a polyfill to allow easy porting of code written for Firefox Extensions.

Excerpt from [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities).

> If you do write your extension to use `browser` and promises, then Firefox also provides a polyfill that will enable it to run in Chrome: https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill.

I followed the tutorial on github to modify the html file for my popup (I removed the CSS classes to make the example more concise):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:800" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../polyfills/browser-polyfill.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center; width: 100vw; min-width: 200px;">
            <button class="btn" id="3">Short Summary</button>
            <button class="btn" id="5">Medium Summary</button>
            <button class="btn" id="7">Long Summary</button>
            <script src="choose_length_page.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Then in my "choose_length_page.js" file, I have the following code:

```
//Enable the polyfill for the content script and execute it in the current tab

browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "../polyfills/browser-polyfill.js" }).then(loadContentScript);

function loadContentScript() {
    browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "../inject-content/inject.js" }).then(listenForClicks);
}

function listenForClicks() {
    document.addEventListener('click', e => {

        if (!e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
            return;
        } else {
            browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
                .then(tabs => {
                    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { summaryLength: e.target.id, targetURL: tabs[0].url });
                });
        }
    });
}
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error ("choose_length_page.html" is the HTML file in this post):

[image: Error]

Why is this error happening, and how can I fix it?

Update 1 -

At the suggestion of wOxxOm, I tried to specify paths qualified from the root package. I did this like so:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:800" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="application/javascript" src="chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/polyfills/browser-polyfill.js"></script>
```

After doing that, I got the following message:

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

So, I don't think that works.

Comment: Specify paths qualified from the root of the package, not relatively.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do I specify paths from the root of the package by using `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/path_to_package`?

Comment: @wOxxOm changing the script tag's `src` attribute to `src="chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/polyfills/browser-polyfill.js"` didn't work because I got the error "browser is undefined" in the popup's javascript file. On further examination the console said "Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked". How do I specify from the root of the package, instead of specifying relatively?

Comment: have you tried just `"/polyfills/browser-polyfill.js"` - as suggested in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript#Parameters)

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried doing that, and it didn't work. I'm starting to think the problem is not with accessing the file itself, because it's not as if I am getting a "Failed to load resource" error (which happens if I set the path to "test").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the errors:

I changed my javascript file to (I added catch statements to the promises and I changed the paths to be consistent with JaromandaX's suggestion):

```
//Enable the polyfill for the content script and execute it in the current tab

browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "/polyfills/browser-polyfill.js" }).then(loadContentScript).catch((error) => logError(error));

function loadContentScript() {
    browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "/inject-content/inject.js" }).then(listenForClicks).catch((error) => logError(error));
}

function listenForClicks() {
    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
            return;
        } else {
            browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
                .then(tabs => {
                    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { summaryLength: e.target.id, targetURL: tabs[0].url });
                });
        }
    });
}

function logError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I also changed the path in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag to:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/polyfills/browser-polyfill.js"></script>
```

The error seemed to be that I did not catch the promises.